# equal heights rows with resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three rows. The medium one is content, left and right menu and such. I am using the jQUery equal heights row script, it works pretty well for normal resolution.
Now there is a problem: To make a responsive layout the right column is not displayed for smaller devices and the left column holds a menu, which is shrunk down to a dropdown. So problem is , when I change the resolution from full to small resolution the left column still has a full height (around 1100px) with drop down menu on top (rest empty). Other way around from small to big the background in the two columns is just as high as the dropdown was before.
As I don't have much idea about javascript, I tried my best but couldn't find a solution.
(building with Bootstrap 3.0)

Javascript so far:

```
   (function($) {
     $.fn.equalHeights = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
      tallest = (minHeight) ? minHeight : 0;
      this.each(function() {
        if($(this).height() > tallest) {
          tallest = $(this).height();
        }
      });
      if((maxHeight) && tallest > maxHeight) tallest = maxHeight;
      return this.each(function() {
        $(this).height(tallest);
      });
    }
  })(jQuery);

$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.height').equalHeights(); 
});
$(window).resize();
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried Math.max()?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Here's a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/6f6Pb/1/

```
function equalHeight(){
    var $colClass = $('.column'), //class name of columns
        heights = $colClass.map( function(){ //get height of all columns, pass it to an array (heights)
            return $(this).height();
        }).get();

    $colClass.height( Math.max.apply(null, heights) );
}

equalHeight();
```

**UPDATE:** I reviewed your question again and I think I didn't understand it the first time. if you want to hide an element on mobile using Bootstrap, just put corresponding responsive utilities class on the element (.visible-md .visible-lg for desktop and large screens, see more here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities). Bootstrap will handle that for you.

If you want to disable the function that computes max height on mobile, use something like this:

```
function equalHeight(){
    if ( $(window).outerWidth() < 480 ) {
        return; //skips entire function when screen is smaller than 480px
    }

    ... //original code here
}
```

or you may use other browser checker in place of window width check (Modernizr, detectbrowser, etc.)

hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** your equalheight plugin should look like this: (should have been width() instead of outerWidth(). sorry)

```
function equalHeight(){
  var $colClass = $('.height'); //class name of columns

  if ( $(window).width() < 992 ) {
    $colClass.height(''); //reset the height of the element
    return; //skips entire function
  }

  var heights = $colClass.map( function(){ //get height of all columns, pass it to an array (heights)
    return $(this).height();
  }).get();

  $colClass.height( Math.max.apply(null, heights) );
}
```

You also have an error in one of your plugins. check console to see what it is. it might be interfering with your other scripts.

Comment: not completely what I'd try to achieve. When you have a full size window (say it's 1920x1080) the columns left and right are the same height, perfekt. The resize window to say 1024x640, the categories collapse to dropdown but still have a very high background box for nohting. - other way round, have a small window and refresh the page, then try to open categories dropdown (= category links will appear without background in the site behind content) or resize to full size, background will stay 40px high, doesn't matter which script. BS visible-* I do use for items not shown

Comment: I think the issue is that the class name for category list for both mobile and desktop are the same (.categorymenu), therefore both are applied with "collapsed" by BS so when you resize it back to larger screen, the category list won't show as it is "collapsed". Try changing the class name of the category list for desktop (>768 etc.) with something else.

Comment: Dan1121 you were right, that was a bug in the menu so it collapsed even maximized again. But the equal height doesn't seem to change, update the code at the link above

Comment: updated the code. take note that I used $(window).outerWidth() before which should be just $(window).width() only.

Comment: I've updated the code once more with this. It seems to work now from small to big but not the other way round. If you have a big size window and resize to small it still shows a lot of empty background color. Any more idea pretty please

Comment: added a height reset when it's less than your width limit. check the updated code

Comment: that works if I add $(window).resize(function(){
  equalHeight(); 
});

Comment: full code currently @Dan1121           function equalHeight(){
  var $colClass = $('.height'); //class name of columns
  
  if ( $(window).width() < 992 ) {
    $colClass.height(''); //reset the height of the element
    return; //skips entire function
  }
  
  var heights = $colClass.map( function(){ //get height of all columns, pass it to an array (heights)
    return $(this).height();
  }).get();

  $colClass.height( Math.max.apply(null, heights) );
}

equalHeight();

$(window).resize(function(){
  equalHeight(); 
});

Comment: with the window.resize function it seems to work decent now, yes. Thank you